# undefined method `articles_path' for #<#<Class:0xb4107fc0>:0xb498bf48>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with pails app in the fle new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   <%= f.text_area :text %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My routes.rb has:

```
  resources :atricles
```

My static_pages_controller.rb has code:

```
  def manager
    @contact_messages = ContactForm.all
    @item = Item.new
    @items = Item.all
    @article = Article.new
  end
```

My articles_controller.rb is:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
       @article = Article.new
    end
    def create
       @article = Article.new article_params
       @article.save
    end

    private

    def article_params
       params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

My migrates file is:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My app/models/article.rb is:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In your `routes.rb`, please correct the spelling. It should be `articles` not `atricles`

Answer (score 2):

typo: `resources :atricles` should be `resources :articles`